# difference of times from different rows mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to write mysql query that can combine two row of the same table and find the difference of the timestamp

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `facebook` (
  `logid` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `times` double DEFAULT '0',
  `userid` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `statusoflogin` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `Game` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`logid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `times` (`times`,`userid`)
)
```

---

### logid | times | userid | statusoflogin | Game|

01    | 12 :30:23   | GT      |  in           |

02    | 12 :45:23   | GT      |  out          |

03    | 01:45:23    | RT      |  in           |

04    | 01:50:23    | GT      |  in           |

05    | 01 :55:23   | RT      |  out          |

06    | 02:05:23    | RT      |  in           |

07    | 02 :10:23   | GT      |  out          |

08    | 02 :40:23   | RT      |  out          |
_-------------------------------------------------------

and the result has to be

### | times.login |times.logout| userid |  duration

| 12 :30:23 |12 :45:23     | GT      |  15
| 01:45:23  |01 :55:23     | RT      |  10
| 01:50:23  |02 :10:23     | GT      |  20
| 02:05:23  | 02 :40:23    | RT      |  35

_----------------------------------------

I used this code but does not give me the required result

```
 SELECT
    fIn.userid,
    fIn.times AS in_time,
    fOut.times AS out_time,
  TIMEDIFF (fOut.times,fIn.times) AS Duration
FROM
    facebook AS fIn
 JOIN
    facebook AS fOut ON (
            fIn.userid = fOut.userid
        AND
            fOut.times > fIn.times)
WHERE fIn.statusoflogin = 'in'
AND fOut.statusoflogin = 'out'
GROUP BY fIn.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are aggregating.  You need to aggregate:

```
SELECT fIn.userid, fIn.times as in_time,
       MIN(fOut.times) as out_time,
       TIMEDIFF(MIN(fOut.times), fIn.times) as Duration
FROM facebook fIn JOIN
     facebook fOut
     ON fIn.userid = fOut.userid AND
        fOut.times > fIn.times)
WHERE fIn.statusoflogin = 'in' AND fOut.statusoflogin = 'out'
GROUP BY fIn.userid, fIn.times;
```